# Different results using OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)) compared to KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I'm implementing a multi-class classifier and I'm getting different results when wrapping KNN in a multi-class classifier.

Unsure why as I understood KNN worked for multiclass already?

```
y = rock_df['Sample_type']
X = rock_df[col_list]

def model_eval(model, X,y):
    """ Function implements classifier model on X and y with a 0.33 test hold out, stratified by y and returns accuracy and standard deviation 
    
    Inputs:
    
        model: The ML model to be tested 
        
        X: the cleaned and preprocessed data (normalized, and NAN dealt with) 
        
        y: Target labels for input data X
    
    """
    #Split train /test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42, stratify = y)
    
    n = X_test.size
    #Fit model 
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    
    #Scoring
    confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
    balanced_accuracy_score( y_test, y_pred)
   
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3)
    mean= scores.mean()
    sd = scores.std()
    print("For {} : {:.1%} accuracy on cross validation, with a standard deviation of {:.1%}".format(model, mean, sd) )
    
    # binomial confidence interval - 95% -- confirm difference with SD
    #interval = 1.96 * sqrt( (mean * (1 - mean)) /n )
    #print('Confidence Interval: {:.3%}'.format(interval) )
    
    
    #return balanced_accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

model = OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2))
model_eval(model, X,y)

model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)
model_eval(model, X,y)
```

First model I get:
For OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)) : 78.6% accuracy on cross validation, with a standard deviation of 5.8%

second:

For KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2) : 83.3% accuracy on cross validation, with a standard deviation of 8.9%

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is OK that you have different results. [`KNeighborsClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier) doesn't employ one-vs-rest strategy; majority vote works with 3 and more classes and there is no need to have OvR in the original implementation. But trying [`OneVsRestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) might be useful as well. I believe that generally decision boundaries will be different. Here I played with [`Iris dataset`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html#sklearn.datasets.load_iris) to get decision boundaries using `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)` and `OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5))`:
[image: KNeighborsClassifier][image: OveVsRestClassifier]

Comment: thank you! would this also hold for RandomForests?